# Tippecanoe throw several errors

Tags: geojson, mapbox, json, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I am trying to create a mbtile by using tippecanoe joining few *.json files:

```
tippecanoe --read-parallel -o name_of_dataset.mbtiles --minimum-zoom=13 --maximum-zoom=16 -l name_of_layer /path/to/where/the/files/are/name_of_dataset_*.json
```

And it throws these errors, json files are extracted form the database using:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E G H I K L M N O P R S T W Y Z;                                                                                  
do
    echo "exporting data beginning with $i"
    psql "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=dbname user=user password=password" -c "\copy (
        SELECT
            jsonb_build_object(
                'type', 'Feature',
                'geometry', st_asgeojson(st_makevalid(st_transform(t1.geom, 4326)))::jsonb,
                'properties', jsonb_build_object(
                    'field1', t1.field1,
                    'field2', t1.field2,
                    'field3', t1.field3
                                       )
           ) AS feature FROM table t1  where left(t1.field1, 1) = '$i') TO '/path/to/where/the/files/are/name_of_dataset_$i.json'"
done
```

Having these three error types:

- Found unexpected character
- Found misspelling of NaN
- Found misspelling of Infinity

have someone experienced similar errors? How can I deal with them? or alternatives to generate .mbtiles form huge table to upload to mapbox. I have been looking in the Tippecanoe documentation but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors geneerating the *.json because some special character in some of the fields.

By  `regexp_replace(field_name,'[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-_\(\)]','','g')` in each field has avoid the error displayed before.

I have also run few queries in those fields where some null value can be presentso:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET field_with_null_values = ''
WHERE field_with_null_values IS NULL;
```

Also when running tippecanoe as it was very large datasets seems that adding --drop-fraction-as-needed at the end of the command has make it work.